# Prove that the adjacency matrix of graph G can be written as in the picture.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let G as a bipartite graph. Show that the adjacency matrix of G can be written as in the picture given below (Actually I don't know how to make that matrix with the dashline like that, can you show me?), but if you ask me to make the matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix} O & P \\ Q & O \end{bmatrix}$

[Adjacency matrix of graph G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZTf7.png)

O, P, and Q are submatrices;
O is a submatrix whose entries are 0 (Zero).
P is a transpose matrix of Q.
I have learn about bipartite graph very well and understand about adjacency matrix, but the problem above seem hard for me to solve (Well, i am stuck)

Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be best if you try it out yourself on any bipartite graph. But make sure that if $U$ and $V$ are two vertex partition sets then the ordering of vertices in adjacency matrix does not mix these subsets.

Answer (score 2):

A [bipartite graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BipartiteGraph.html) has vertices in two sets $S_1$ (size $n$) and $S_2$ (size $m$), such that all vertices are either in $S_1$ or in $S_2$, and the vertices in $S_1$ are not connected to other vertices in $S_1$, and the vertices in $S_2$ are not connected to other vertices in $S_2$.

You can sort the vertices as follows
$$\text{vertices}=\left\{\underbrace{v_1,\cdots,v_n}_{\in S_1},\underbrace{v_{n+1},\cdots,v_{n+m}}_{\in S_2}\right\}$$
Because the vertices in $S_1$ are not connected to other vertices in $S_1$, you know that the $(1,1)$ block in your adjacency matrix must be zero, and the same for your $(2,2)$ block.

Answer (score 1):

A bipartite graph is conventionally represented with each part ordered consecutively, so that the adjacency matrix of a bipartite graph with parts $S_1$ and $S_2$ is the block matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 0_{|S_1|} & A \\ A^{T} & 0_{|S_2|}\end {bmatrix} $$ where $0_{n} $ is a $n \times n $ matrix of zeroes, and $A $ is a $|S_1|\times |S_2|$ matrix indicating adjacency between elements of $S_1$ and $S_2$. From this structure, the symmetry of eigenvalues can be seen using algebra (not only using combinatorics).